# "Featured Tag" or other way to promote tags with low response levels

Tags: feature-request, tags, site-promotion

It seems that one of the challenges in the SO community is getting specific domain questions answered by "experts" in that area. There have been quite a few times that I have asked things that have little to no views and certainly no answers or no answers that are acceptable. I know I'm not the only one in this. Conversely, I've seen quite a few questions where I have no idea and it looks like (again...I'm not the only one) no one else knows either.

To back up my claim, take an example tag: "java". It has (as I am writing this) ~83K questions with ~11K unanswered or roughly 13.25% unanswered.

Conversely, the sub-domain of java tag: "osgi". It has (as I am writing this) 422 questions with 95 unanswered or roughly 22.5% unanswered.

These are just examples that I have came up with, I am sure there are probably better ones.

SO is a much better venue than the old forums and email list style of Q&A IMO, but it also seems to lack (in some cases) the "experts".

Since you obviously can't pay them :) Are there any other ways to attract talented experts for specific tags, perhaps a "featured tag" that grants bonus rep for accepted answers of low threshold tags?

Or maybe it's all in my head :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can already promote specific question using the [Bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Experts in a specific tag likely already have said tag in their favorite tags list, which causes it to come up considerably more frequently on the Interesting tab.

I answer questions in the java tag all the time and know absolutely nothing about osgi.  I'd be rather annoyed if questions I can't answer suddenly started coming up considerably more often.

Comment: Hmm, that's not really what I'm asking - to push the question up in view rank. I'm asking if we can "lure" experts by offering an incentive. The bounty question works for specific questions, but I would contend that it doesn't really work for specific tags.